# Escaping libraries for Java using character streams

Tags: java, security, xss

Are there any HTML/JavaScript escaping libraries for Java that have a character stream interface?

Comment: What do you want to escape? Marriage?

Comment: @Michael - do you have a library for that? :o

Comment: What exaclty do you want to escape in HTML/JS? You may try [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Comment: @Michael StringEscapeUtils is not a great choice for preventing XSS attacks. Its `escapeEcmaScript` method is fundamentally broken if you consider XSS protection. OWASP ESAPI is preferred over Apache Commons Lang, for exactly this purpose. You can compare JavaScriptCodec from ESAPI to escapeEcmaScript, and you'll notice the difference in the approaches taken.

Comment: Plus StringEscapeUtils doesn't have a streams interface. I don't believe ESAPI does either, other than for Base64 encoding.

Comment: @pepsi, yes, ESAPI also doesn't have an API that accepts streams. But why do you need one? Can you not read from the stream into `String` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  [Caja's `Escaping` class](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/lexer/escaping/Escaping.java) provides escapers that append the escaped text to an `Appendable` for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JavaScript regex content, JSON, and XML.  Java `Writer`s implement `Appendable` as do `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

It also allows escaping JavaScript in a mode that allows it to be embedded in an HTML `<script>` element or XML CDATA section without further escaping by encoding angle brackets.

```
/**
 * Given a plain text string writes an unquoted javascript string literal.
 *
 * @param s the plain text string to escape.
 * @param asciiOnly Makes sure that only ASCII characters are written to out.
 *     This is a good idea if you don't have control over the charset that
 *     the javascript will be served with.
 * @param embeddable True to make sure that nothing is written to out that
 *     could interfere with embedding inside a script tag or CDATA section, or
 *     other tag that typically contains markup.
 *     This does not make it safe to embed in an HTML attribute without
 *     further escaping.
 * @param out written to.
 */
public static void escapeJsString(
    CharSequence s, boolean asciiOnly, boolean embeddable, Appendable out)
    throws IOException
```

and there's a convenient method with the same name but that takes a `StringBuilder` and does not require you to handle `IOException`.

Comment: Looks like there's an stream interface for output, but not input. I've come to the conclusion that there is no library with both though, so your answer is the closest match.